# Blazor @onclick event to close a single item inside a loop

Tags: c#, event-handling, dom-events, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using a Razorcomponent with a Blazor server app. The app polls for alertmessages on the server.
The server might send back several messages, which I loop over.
The class on the div has a "show" and "hidden" and that takes care of hiding elements.

The problem I have is that I want to be able to close each `alertmessage` and not all- which happens as described in the below simplified code:

```
--snip
@if(alert.valid == true){
    @foreach(var alert in alerts){
        @if(alert.type == "alert")
        <div id="alertmessage" class="@show">
            <button type="button" @onclick="@show">Hide this element</button>
        </div>
    
    }
}
@code{
    private string value { get; set;} = "show";
    private void Show() {
        value = "hidden";
     }
}
```

As per the above example, if there are several alerts, the method `Show()` will close all the boxes, and it produces x count of `<div id="alertmessage"` I get this, but is there a way to grab that specific element like alert.id or something? Appreciate all feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In blazor you work everytime with objects , you should do a class for the alert and change its attribute on the for each.

The page has to contain a list of alert objects as attribute.

More less this:

```
@if(alert.valid == true){
    @foreach(var alert in alerts){
        
        <div id="alertmessage" class="@show">
            <button type="button" hidden="@alert.hidden" @onclick="()=>show(alert)">Hide this element</button>
        </div>
    
    }
}
@code{
    private string value { get; set;} = "show";
    
    
    private List<Alert> alerts = new();
    private void Show(Alert alert) {
        alert.hidden = true;
        alert.message= "whatever"
     }
     
     
     public class Alert{
     public String message = "whatever"
     public bool hidden = false;
     //other stuff
     }
}
```

If you want to separate the logic from the presentation you can declare alert logic in its own class -file .